# Standard notion for sequence of polynomial terms exponents

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials

If we have a polynomial on the form: $a_{1}x^{k_{1}}, a_{2}x^{k_{2}} , \cdots , a_{n}x^{k_{n}}$, where $a_{1},a_{2}, \cdots a_{n}$ are non zero coefficients. 
We want to obtain the sequence of exponents $k_{1},k_{2}, \cdots k_{n}$, but we want every exponent repeated with the term's coefficient number.
Example: $p(x) = 2x^{3} + 3x^{2}$, then we obtain the sequence: $3,3,2,2,2$.

Is there a standard notion for this? if not any ideas on how to formulate it in a precise but short way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps,

> Let $k_1,\ldots,k_m$ be the unique non-increasing sequence of non-negative integers with $p(x)=\sum_{i=1}^mx^{k_i}$.